# Prove that a curve is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\alpha$ a map such that:

$\alpha(x)=
  \left \{
    \begin{aligned}
      (x,0,\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}))&& if \quad x>0\\
      (x,\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}),0)&& if \quad x<0\\
      (0,0,0) && if \quad x=0
    \end{aligned}
  \right .
\
$

Prove that $\alpha$ is differentiable.

**My attempt**

Note that $\alpha$ is differentiable in $x\not =0$ because if $x>0$ then $(x,0,\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}))$ is a function of $C^1$ class.

Analogous if $x<0$.

However,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\alpha(x+0)-\alpha(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\alpha(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(1,0,\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})}{x})=(1,0,0)$

Analogous

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\alpha(x+0)-\alpha(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\alpha(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(1,\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})}{x},0)=(1,0,0)$

Then, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} = \frac{\alpha(x+0)-\alpha(0)}{x}$ this implies by definition that $\alpha$ is differentiable in $x=0$.

In consequence,

$\alpha$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$

Is correct my proof?

Regards.

Comment: Shouldn't you do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions)?

Comment: @Snoop you have linked to the definition of derivative for a function of several variables. A curve is a function of only one variable, so a simpler definition of derivative may be used.

Comment: @Pétur understood